# REINFORCE with continuous actions diverging

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement the REINFORCE algorithm for continuous action space. I've created a toy, one-state MDP where the reward is the negative of the absolute difference between the action chosen and a target value. The optimal strategy is for the action to be identical to the target value. The range of possible actions is -inf to inf. For example, if the target value is 5 and the agent takes action 2.2, the reward is -2.8 = -abs(2.2-5) and the episode terminates. A neural network with a single linear neuron predicts the mean of a Gaussian distribution that has a fixed standard deviation that the agent samples its action from. The MDP state has a feature vector which is just [1.0].

When the standard deviation is small, say 0.05, the network converges nicely. However, when the standard deviation is larger, say 0.5, the network's prediction diverges in the opposite direction of the target value.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tf.enable_eager_execution()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mean_input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    mean_output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                                1, activation='linear')(mean_input_layer)
    mean_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=mean_input_layer, 
                                outputs=mean_output_layer)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)

    target_mean = 5
    standard_deviation = 0.05 # Works
    # standard_deviation = 0.5 # Diverges

    for t in range(10000):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            mean = mean_model(np.array([[1]]), training=True)
            stdev = np.array([[standard_deviation]], dtype=np.float32)
            dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=mean, scale=stdev)
            samp = dist.sample()
            ascent = -(dist.log_prob(samp)*(-tf.math.abs(samp-target_mean)))
            mean_grads = tape.gradient(ascent, mean_model.trainable_variables) 
            optimizer.apply_gradients(
                zip(mean_grads, mean_model.trainable_variables))
            print('#' + str(t) 
                   + ' Sample: ' + str(samp.numpy()[0]) 
                   + ' Mean: ' + str(mean.numpy()[0]))
```

The variable "ascent" is negative with the intention that gradient ascent, not descent, is performed.

Here's an example run with a target value of 5 and a standard deviation of 0.05:

#0 Sample: [-0.3368746] Mean: [-0.400553]

#1 Sample: [-0.35207522] Mean: [-0.3980214]

#2 Sample: [-0.39965397] Mean: [-0.3947122]

#3 Sample: [-0.3883655] Mean: [-0.39056838]

...

#2460 Sample: [5.0231776] Mean: [4.9940543]

#2461 Sample: [5.030905] Mean: [4.99024]

#2462 Sample: [4.853626] Mean: [4.9867477]

#2463 Sample: [4.8647094] Mean: [4.983813]

#2464 Sample: [4.9929175] Mean: [4.982292]

It converges.

Here's an example run with a target value at 5 and a standard deviation of 0.5:

#1 Sample: [0.6297094] Mean: [1.4340767]

#2 Sample: [0.75481075] Mean: [1.4310371]

#3 Sample: [0.9269088] Mean: [1.4287564]

#4 Sample: [1.2933123] Mean: [1.4272974]

...

#3210 Sample: [-3.4329443] Mean: [-3.322072]

#3211 Sample: [-3.755511] Mean: [-3.3225727]

#3212 Sample: [-3.6817236] Mean: [-3.3237739]

#3213 Sample: [-3.4897459] Mean: [-3.324738]

...

#9996 Sample: [-13.280873] Mean: [-13.032175]

#9997 Sample: [-13.879341] Mean: [-13.032874]

#9998 Sample: [-12.796365] Mean: [-13.036192]

#9999 Sample: [-13.04003] Mean: [-13.036874]

It diverges in the opposite direction of the target value.
What's going on here? Is there a bug in my implementation? Thanks for the help.

**Update:** If I replace "samp = dist.sample()" with a sample from a uniform distribution centered at the mean with a width of +- 2 standard deviations, the 0.5 standard deviation case converges. Specifically, "samp = tf.constant([[mean.numpy()[0] - 2*standard_deviation + 4*standard_deviation*np.random.random()]])". This is clearly not a real solution to the problem, but might offer some insight to someone trying to figure out what's going wrong here. I'm still looking for a solution.

**Update 2:** As another piece to the puzzle, if I flip the sign of the ascent variable then the 0.5 standard deviation case converges and the 0.05 standard deviation case diverges.

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space for this kind of additional info (including code!) - edit & update your post instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've deleted the comment and added it to the post.

Comment: You can do better and format your code snippets appropriately

Comment: Use the squared distance instead of abs. It is a quadratic function, thus smooth and differentiable, unlike abs. This is a general rule.
You are updating only the mean, right? The std never changes, meaning that your search distribution is always large and it may give you always large update steps. Try to use Adam or another opt rather than SGD. However, this does not explain why it works after your "update".

Comment: I've updated "tf.math.abs" to "tf.math.square" and tried "...optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)" and "...optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.95)" with no luck. I believe the calculated gradient is moving the mean in the wrong direction.